# Output a YAML::Node

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

How can I convert a YAML::Node into a stream/string for saving to a file? For example (taken from the tutorial):

```cpp
YAML::Node node;  // starts out as null
node["key"] = "value";  // it now is a map node
node["seq"].push_back("first element");  // node["seq"] automatically becomes a sequence
node["seq"].push_back("second element");

node["mirror"] = node["seq"][0];  // this creates an alias
node["seq"][0] = "1st element";  // this also changes node["mirror"]
node["mirror"] = "element #1";  // and this changes node["seq"][0] - they're really the "same" node

node["self"] = node;  // you can even create self-aliases
node[node["mirror"]] = node["seq"];  // and strange loops :)
```

How can I now dump `node` to a file?

Comment: Hi Baruch, here is a good tutorial that I've used before on this sort of thing https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-yaml-to-a-file-in-node-js-javascript/ I'm not sure if this has what you are looking for (part way down it talks about writing a yaml file). Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: @GuyLawrence-Downs That is for javascript. I am asking specifically about the c++ library yaml-cpp